# Como generar Json con estructura diferente a la estandar

Tags: php, mysql, json, nodejs

Buenas noches compañeros.
Actualmente estoy generando apis en Node para generar consultas Json, sin embargo la estructura de Node para Json, es la "estandar", por ejemplo, la siguiente:

La base de datos la tengo en mysql

```
{"data":[
{
   "id":1,
   "nombre":"VARIEDADES ESPERANZA",
   "direccion":"MIAMI",
   "telefono_fijo":"5922926",
   "telefono_movil":"59229269",
   "mail":"variedades@zuleta.com",
   "user_id":1,
   "Estado":"Chicago"
}]}
```

Sin embargo necesito una estructura diferente, como la siguiente:

```
{
   "DataSources":[
      {
         "Id":"24791",
         "Rows":[
            [
               1,
               "2021-02-23T07:00:00.000Z",
               1,
               "STORE MIAMI ARGUETA",
               100033271,
               "",
               "",
               "",
               "CARLOS ARGUETA",
               "MIAMI",
               252025252,
               0,
               "USA",
               "FLORIDA",
               "MIAMI",
               33271,
               "CARLOSARGUE@GMAIL.COM",
               "20*20*20",
               125,
               0,
               "NO",
               null,
               25,
               "KARLA FLORES",
               "GUATEMALA ZONA 10",
               125222,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               "GUATEMALA",
               "GUATEMALA",
               "GUATEMALA"
            ],
            [
               25,
               "2021-03-07T07:00:00.000Z",
               3,
               "",
               252000,
               "",
               "",
               "",
               "John Week",
               "DR 2500",
               25251414,
               0,
               "",
               "Luisiana",
               "Georgetown",
               6500,
               "",
               "",
               125,
               0,
               "",
               null,
               10,
               "Carlos Argueta",
               "14 calle 8-96",
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               "Guatemala",
               "Guatemala",
               "Guatemala"
            ]
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

La consulta es: como hago para generar un Json con estructura diferente a la estandar?  habrá algún tutorial o guía para hacerla?

Quedo atento.

Saludos!

Comment: Eso sigue siendo una estructura estándar, la única diferencia es que en lugar de objetos con `clave: valor` estás usando arreglos. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código con el que armas los datos, solo así podemos tratar de ayudarte.

Comment: El código que utilizo en node es:                             
 aplicacion.get('/api/tguias', function(peticion,respuesta){
  pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
    const query = `SELECT * FROM bdtrackingguias`
    connection.query(query,function(error,filas,campos){
      respuesta.json({data:filas})
    })
    connection.release()
  })
})